# Comparing 2 values in dict to all other values

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an easy way to compare 2 values in a dictionary to all other values?
For example, if I have a dict:

```
dict = {A:12, B:1, C:14, D:13, E:3, F: 4}
```

I'd want to find all values that can be added together to equal another values. E.g. A + B = D, so A,B, and D would be returned.

Comment: If by "easy way" you mean inbuilt function, then no. You'll have to go the "hard way" of comparing the additions yourself.

Comment: Can there be multiple values on both sides of the equation?  (For example, `A + D + B = C + A` - do you want to find values like that)?

Comment: FYI, that's not correct Python dictionary syntax - you want quotes around your keys, and your values if they're strings.

Comment: @SeanVieira, that would be a more interesting question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
d = {'A':12, 'B':1, 'C':14, 'D':13, 'E':3, 'F': 4}

import itertools
for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(sorted(d, key=d.get), 3):
    if d[a] + d[b] == d[c]:
        print(a,b,c)
```

---

```
B E F
B A D
B D C
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want duplicates use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` instead:

```
d = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':4}

import itertools
for a, b, c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sorted(d, key=d.get), 3):
    if d[a] + d[b] == d[c]:
        print(a,b,c)
```

---

```
A A B
B B C
```

**Why `sorted` is used?**

Comparing `x + y` == `z` is meaningless, if `x` or `y` is is larger than `z`. (assuming all values are positive integer). I used `sorted` to arrange data;  `x <= y <= z`.

Another side effect of sorting: If `A + B == C` is True, `B + A == C` is also True. But using `sorted`, only one is printed.

---

BTW, Don't use `dict` as variable name. It shadows builtin `dict` function.

Comment: I assumed duplicates would be allowed, eg if `B=2` then `B + B = D`. You might want to explain why `sorted` is needed here.

Comment: How does `sorted` sorts based on value when `key` is `d.get`? Will the key function be passed the actual keys from dict?

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes it does a "sort by value"

Comment: @thefourtheye, `d.get` is similar to `d[..]`. Return value of the `key` function is used to compare inside the sort function.

Comment: @gnibbler, I added an explanation. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy, but not very efficient (ok for small dicts)

```
>>> D = {'A':12, 'B':1, 'C':14, 'D':13, 'E':3, 'F': 4}
>>> 
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for i, j, k in product(D.items(), repeat=3):
...     if i[1] + j[1] == k[1]:
...         print "{} + {} = {}".format(i[0], j[0], k[0])
... 
A + B = D
B + A = D
B + E = F
B + D = C
E + B = F
D + B = C
```

Comment: It gives duplicates as well.

Comment: @thefourtheye, that was my interpretation of "all values". also see my comment on falsetru's answer

Answer (score 2):

This runs in O(n^2) on non-pathological inputs (e.g. all zeroes), rather than O(n^3) like the other answers here, and correctly handles duplicates.

```
def addTriples(d):
    inverse = {v:[] for v in d.itervalues()}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        inverse[v].append(k)

    for k1, v1 in d.iteritems():
        for k2, v2 in d.iteritems():
            if k1 != k2:
                for k3 in inverse.get(v1 + v2, ()):
                    if k2 != k3:
                        yield (k1, k2, k3)

d = {'A':12, 'B':1, 'C':14, 'D':13, 'E':3, 'F':4}
for triple in addTriples(d):
    print triple
```

Remove `k1 != k2` and `k2 != k3` if you want to allow A + A = B and A + B = A

Comment: @falsetru, you are correct. (It was an edit for clarity that went bad.) It is fixed.